# Should the volume be ON by default? ( for OUR type of Site )

Tags: high-volume

http://juicycanvas.com/

I remember this debate 10-years ago on flash sites.. 
but I'm not sure if it has still stood the test of time. 
The target audience is 17-28yrs old.

thoughts?

Comment: No. Uses up data. Is unexpected/unwelcome; invasive/ embarrassing/annoying depending on where users are. Goes against W3C standards for accessibility. Nothing wrong with music/audio, but autoplay is frowned upon for many reasons (doesn't work on most mobile browsers anyway). 
http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/5252/video-and-audio-autoplay-evidence-that-its-bad-practice
http://www.punkchip.com/2009/04/autoplay-is-bad-for-all-users/

Comment: @JonW thanks for referencing the link, but maybe its better to answer it in the context of our particular type of site and target?

Comment: @mc01 - here is an example of autoplay enabled on a very high-profile site made by a top former UX designer from google : http://Canva.com/about

Comment: You're not really asking a general question - you're asking for a review of a feature of your site. That's not really going to benefit anyone else reading this question. At least as a duplicate it's linking to a question that is of use to more people.

Comment: ...Your example site has no audio (except the YouTube video, which users control). On a phone, the main video is replaced with still images. Your site on desktop lets me know there's a video & I can turn audio on if I want to, which is great. It doesn't blast me by default (whether I'm in HS math class, or my desk at work - age is irrelevant). My phone doesn't show a video at all (autoplay HTML audio/video doesn't work on mobile!) - just a black box that seems broken. A shame, because it's a cool video. Enable "controls", put a poster frame up, and turn off "autoplay" at least on mobile.

Comment: thanks @mc01 that is really helpful - hopefully not just to me but to many others with a similar type of site.

Comment: (complete aside, your own video is fun, but are those all licensed clips? If not, you may be running into some legal issues...)

Answer (score 2):

NO. NO! NO!! NO!!! NO!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Don't 20 somethings work? Don't teens and 20 somethings have parents, significant others, room mates and others? Sometimes you need to be quiet and the last thing you need is SOUND.

Yes you can turn the sound off, or have head phones - but we all forget don't we?

So the answer is NO!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: and *if* I have headphones on, I'm probably already listening to something *else* anyways. :)

Comment: so true. so true.