# is it good idea to have some music play on App Launch

Tags: android, user-expectation, music

I am developing an Android that is based on bodybuilding and my launch screen currently consists of a video of some athletes training in the background. The background score is reasonably good and pumps you up (i think). There are two buttons Login and Sign up on this screen and hence the user might not stay on this screen for long.

On working on the app for some time now, I have started to find the music a little annoying (but that might be possibly because I have to listen to it so often). I was wondering if I should mute it in the app.

What are your thoughts? Is it okay to have the app play music when someone starts it for the first time, or is it an annoying feature?

Comment: The answer is simply NO. Don't auto play music. Especially if it's going to go on forever. If you think the music is there to help the user in some way, have it disabled by default and let the user decide if they want to play it. Refer this question. There are some good points discussed here although it's about "sound effects". http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/53641/should-i-add-sound-effects-to-my-web-site and also this - http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/5252/video-and-audio-autoplay-evidence-that-its-bad-practice/5255#5255

Comment: This was overdone in the Flash error. It is beyond annoying; it will in most cases frustrate and even anger your users. This is something you need to ask the users permission for. Like Leths said, if absolutely necessary, let the user activate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seriously, don't prompt with music unless your app is a game, a video or a music app.

If that music is not absolutely necessary to make your app work, or let's say to make your app 100% immersive or effective, then you should not force the user with such things.

Furthermore, in a mobile app, your user could trigger the app in many context, even by mistake it could be annoying if, let's say, your app played music in public transports or at work...

If I were to keep the music, I would cut it by default and let the user activate it by self.

You will probably end up with less frustration for your users by removing this music by default.

Comment: Wat Leths says, Also Is it required to display the video? I would feel like uninstalling an app when it starts with music and/or a video, I just want the damn thing to load up.

Comment: I have muted the music. Well, the video was just for effects  and the video is just an replacement for a  static background. It doesn't delay the app from starting-up in anyway. Will you recommend against a video in this case as well?

Comment: A video for a background is extremely distracting. The question is also whether the extra app size from the video is justified.